# C++ Read From Socket into std::string

Tags: c++, sockets, stdstring

I am writing a program in c++ that uses c sockets. I need a function to receive data that I would like to return a string. I know this will not work:

```
std::string Communication::recv(int bytes) {
    std::string output;
    if (read(this->sock, output, bytes)<0) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to read data from socket.\n";
    }
    return output;
}
```

Because the `read()`* function takes a char array pointer for an argument. What is the best way to return a string here? I know I could theoretically read the data into a char array then convert that to a string but that seems wasteful to me. Is there a better way?

*I don't actually mind using something other that `read()` if there is a more fitting alternative

Here is all of the code on pastebin which should expire in a week. If I don't have an answer by then I will re-post it: http://pastebin.com/HkTDzmSt

**[UPDATE]**

I also tried using `&output[0]` but got the output contained the following:

```
jello!
[insert a billion bell characters here]
```

"jello!" was the data sent back to the socket.

Comment: c_str() is const, you can't do it. just read into a buffer then copy to a string.

Comment: @billz Correct, I retract my suggestion.

Comment: Is this even proper form? If not is there something I should do differently?

Comment: @billz &output[0] might work though. A bit sketchy but it avoids a mem copy.

Comment: @EricFortin why `&output[0]` and not just `&output`?

Comment: output[0] returns a reference to the first character. You need a pointer for the socket to write in so you take the address of that reference. You can do it since character in the string are contiguous in memory. &output would point to the string object and not a buffer you could write in.

Comment: @EricFortin I tried your suggestion and it worked (almost). The output was followed by a whole bunch of unprintable characters.

Comment: @735Tesla You still need to check how many bytes returned from `read` function.

Comment: @735Tesla Are you only expecting ascii character from your socket ? std::string are allowed to contain \0 within the string as well as any bytes you can put in. These might not be printable, they might be UTF8 etc..

Comment: @billz doesn't the third function argument limit the amount of bytes read to the integer specified?

Comment: @EricFortin I am using netcat to test the socket. All I sent to the program should have been `jello!\n`

Comment: The 3rd parameter is the *max* that can be read.  You can read less (i.e. short read).  This IMO is the less interesting aspect.  What happens when you accidentally plop more into the raw string than is allocated or the string object knows about in its length variable?

Comment: @735Tesla Either you send a \0 from the other end or you add it yourself from within your client code if you want to print.

Comment: @Duck Would that put a bunch of null bytes at the end of the string?

Comment: @EricFortin I will write a python program to test it because it will be really simple

Comment: @735Tesla, no not on its own.  But if you go this route you can put it there yourself.

Comment: @EricFortin I wrote a python program to test mine and still have the same problem: http://puu.sh/6tAnc.png http://puu.sh/6tApn.png

Comment: @EricFortin the first picture is the python server and the second is the output I get when I run my program. The part about the socket being closed is what it prints when it closes the socket, not data it received.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some functions that should help you accomplish what you want. It assumes you'll only receive ascii character from the other end of the socket.

```
std::string Communication::recv(int bytes) {
    std::string output(bytes, 0);
    if (read(this->sock, &output[0], bytes-1)<0) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to read data from socket.\n";
    }
    return output;
}
```

or

```
std::string Communication::recv(int bytes) {
    std::string output;
    output.resize(bytes);

    int bytes_received = read(this->sock, &output[0], bytes-1);
    if (bytes_received<0) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to read data from socket.\n";
        return "";
    }

    output[bytes_received] = 0;
    return output;
}
```

When printing the string, be sure to use `cout << output.c_str()` since string overwrite `operator<<` and skip unprintable character until it reaches size. Ultimately, you could also resize at the end of the function to the size received and be able to use normal `cout`.

As pointed out in comments, sending the size first would also be a great idea to avoid possible unnecessary memory allocation by the string class.

Comment: I still get the same output I linked in my last comment. The interesting thing is that it appears that the bell characters are about equal to the length of "jello!" subtracted from 1024 (the parameter I am currently using as `bytes`)

Comment: @735Tesla You should send the length of your string first. Then when receiving, you read that length first to know how much to read next. By using a fixed length for receive, you will be waiting for nothing and/or reading garbage into your string.

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan Thanks. I hadn't though of doing that. Is there still a way to dynamically receive input though?

Comment: Try printing the output string like so: cout << output.c_str() << endl; String overwrite operator<< and skip bytes that are 0 and continue until size is reached.

Comment: @EricFortin That worked! Thank you! Could you add that to your answer?

Comment: Why read only `bytes-1` into a buffer sized `bytes`? Why set `output[bytes_received]=0` even when `bytes_received < 0`? Questions, questions...

Comment: Thanks for pointing the missing return in the error case. As for why read 1 byte less than `bytes`, it was to ensure a null terminated byte string(I said at the beginning I was assuming only ascii characters). We could also resize to `bytes+1` and read `bytes` bytes.